# Elasticsearch Aggregation doesn't work the way it should

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of messages where I store `messageHash` for each `message` too. I also have many more fields along with them. There are multiple duplicate `message` fields in the index e.g. "Hello". I want to retrieve unique messages.

Here is the query I wrote to search unique messages and sort them by date.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "message": "Hello"
        }
      },
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user1": "guest"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "user2": "guest"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_messages": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "messageHash"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_messages_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
              "_score"
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I still get duplicate messages and it's not sorted by date either! It's just like I've not added the aggregation. I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: How are you sending your query?

Comment: I figured out the problem! I was not scrolling down to see `"aggregations" : {
    "top_messages" : {` in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else having same problem... Remember that the response would be something like this:

```
{
  "took" : X,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : X,
    "successful" : X,
    "failed" : X
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : X,
    "max_score" : X,
    "hits" : [
            ....
            ....
           ]
},
  "aggregations" : {
    "top_messages" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : X,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : X,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "doc_count" : X,
          "top_messages_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : X,
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                    .....
                    .....
                   ]
}
```

You will get the query results without aggregation in the first segment. Just scroll down and check the aggregation segment.

If you don't want the first segment you can pass `"size"=0` in the query as documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/returning-only-agg-results.html